# What is the pattern? Level 8 question 72

Tags: think-different

1, 3, 11, 47, ??

I'm stuck on a level. I have tried guessing a few numbers but can't see a pattern. Can anyone solve the following sequence?

Comment: If you could tell what numbers you guessed, it would be a bit easier for people to help you.

Comment: if you could please add the level and  question, that would be helpful for others who encounter the same problem

Answer (score 4):

The answer is 239.

1*2 = 2 and 2+1 = 3,
3*3 = 9 and 9+2 = 11,
11*4 = 44 and 44+3 = 47,
47*5 = 235 and 235+4 = 239